# Run a task after run

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.6

I start some docker containers before executing `run` to start my play-framework project:

`run in Compile := (run in Compile dependsOn(dockerComposeUp)).evaluated`

Now I'd like to tear down all docker containers using `dockerComposeDown`  when play stops. Any ideas on how to accomplish on this?

I've already gone through [Doing something after an input task](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-After-Input-Task.html), but that starts the containers and immediatly stops them again. (In fact it even stops the containers before starting them.) Here is what I tried:

```
run in Compile := {
  (run in Compile dependsOn(dockerComposeUp)).evaluated
  dockerComposeDown.value
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different approach is to call your docker task sequentially to run task. You could achieve this as described below:

```
lazy val testPrint =  taskKey[Unit]("showTime")
testPrint := {
  println("Test print.")
}

lazy val testRun =  taskKey[Unit]("test build")
testRun := {

  Def.sequential((runMain in Compile).toTask(" com.mycompany.MainClass "), testPrint).value
}
```

First define the testPrint task which in your case could be the dockerTask and then define testRun which will run both tasks sequentially. To run this just do *sbt testRun*. After execution it should print out "Test print."

Comment: Thx a lot! I ended up defining my `run` task as: `run in Compile := Def.sequential((run in Compile dependsOn(dockerComposeUp)).toTask(""), dockerComposeDown).value`

Comment: So you re-assigned run in Compile actually :) perfect